# How specifically does one configure a reverse proxy for a custom branded login URL?

Tags: partner-communities, ssl

We are trying to launch MyDomain.example.com instead of mydomain.force.com for our partner community. I've gleaned that reverse proxy is the only workaround to make this happen and was able to get an EC2 instance running apache's reverse proxy successfully, but the cookie keeps redirecting to the salesforce branded login page. How do we override this cookie OR is there a better method of having a branded login? SSO? iFrame did NOT work : (